# Explanation needed on sample MIPS example

Tags: assembly, mips

So i have a sample question for an upcoming mips test and needed a clarification.

1. Suppose word array A stores 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, in this order. Assume the starting address of A is currently in $s0. After the following instructions, what will be the value in $t1?

> ori $t0, $0, 6
>
> ```
> p7L0: lw $t1, 0($s0)
> sll $t1, $t1, 2
> blt $t0, $t1, p7L1
> addi $s0, $s0, 4 
> j p7L0
> ```
>
> p7L1:

(a) 2
(b) 3
(c) 6
(d) None of the above.

In this example the answer comes out to 8. Yet im kind of confused how it got that. In my run through, in the command ori i get 6. It goes to the sll and it comes out with 0. Since 0 is less than 6, it branches to p7L1:

Clarification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sll` instruction multiplies t1 by 4, so its value each time throught the loop will be 0, 4, 8, and then the branch will be taken, because 6 < 8. Hence the answer is 8.